# Building dynamic rule set and validating against multiple objects in runtime C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, rule-engine

I already have a custom-built CMS using which we define promo cards which are consumed by another site and display it. Until now it is showing all the promo cards declared over there in custom CMS, Right now the requirement is, I want to introduce rulesets to be assigned to these cards under CMS so the consuming site has to validate it against the respective object properties in the consuming app and show it if the ruleset passes the validation.

I have gone through a couple of libraries out there that provides an option of defining dynamic rulesets
against dynamic objects,

This one looks promising
https://github.com/microsoft/RulesEngine

As it provides an option to define ruleset dynamically, but i am not sure whether the path i going through the right path so that it will be future proof, and also i need to know the best practies while implementing the dynamic access check behavior.

Any assistance would greatly help. Thanks and looking forward to your suggestions and advice on the above

Comment: I think you are on the right path, decisions on what rules engine to use are strict related to costs and integration. One thing that you might want to consider in your architecture is a workflow engine, what today is just validations or end results based on a set of rules, tomorrow might be a process management (workflows) so have that in mind when choosing your rule engine what problems you could address in the future.

Comment: About the access, if I get that right, in distributed systems you trust upper layers, as an example, if your access gate says user can do that thing you will let him do it without checking any of his permissions again and again on deeper layers. So if your token says user can do that, then let it do it, or if the token is more of a key to the gate than establish his possible actions as first step when receiving his demands.

Comment: Hi @SilentTremor Thanks for your suggestions, As of now the requirement is to show some personalized cards based on the dynamic rules which can be changed by business people anytime, So basically i want to provide options for the admin to change the rules manually for some cards so that it will show to the respective users. One more question, What is the best use case for using workflow engine.

Comment: An event, triggers a task, task that has a static or dynamic workflow, example, orders, with orders placement, order payment, order delivery.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this might help however the NRules engine might help you in what you are trying to achieve for dynamic rule engine based on properties:

https://github.com/NRules/NRules/wiki/Getting-Started